# Hierarchical CMake project that also works when building an "inner" (non-root) project

Tags: cmake, build

Suppose I have a hierarchical CMake project, composed of `n` different projects:

```
CMakeLists.txt
proj-1/CMakeLists.txt
proj-2/CMakeLists.txt
(...)
proj-n/CMakeLists.txt
```

Evidently there'll be the source files for each project as well.

I'd ensure all commands of interest are added to the root `CMakeLists.txt` file -- say, `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`, `enable_testing()`, `add_compile_options()`, etc. If I understand correctly, whichever options are included in the root `CMakeLists.txt` file are also applied to all children `CMakeLists.txt` file -- please correct me if I'm wrong, since I'm counting on this behavior. The root `CMakeLists.txt` also contains an `add_subdirectory(proj-X)` statement for each `X` = 1, ..., n.

Anyway. Suppose, for some reason, that I would like to build only one of the `proj-X` folders, say `proj-1`. Maybe the build is broken in one of the other projects, or maybe I need to fix a bug on `proj-1`, it doesn't depend on the other projects, and it would take forever to build all projects.

The point is: I would like to run `cmake` on `proj-1/CMakeLists.txt` rather than on the root `CMakeLists.txt` file, and yet I would like to ensure that `proj-1` is built in exactly the same way it would be build, had I run `cmake` on the root `CMakeLists.txt` file. This is an issue since the root `CMakeLists.txt` contains statements that the children `CMakeLists.txt` should "inherit" from in the regular situation where it's built from the root, and yet in this scenario I'm building directly from `proj-1/CMakeLists.txt` (the root `CMakeLists.txt` file doesn't come into the picture in this scenario.)

One possibility, as I understand, would be to copy all options from the root `CMakeLists.txt` file to every other `proj-X/CMakeLists.txt` file. Of course, this is a hack and a maintenance nightmare, but I suppose it would work.

Are there other possible solutions? Can I, say, create a file containing all the common options and save it to the root, and then do the CMake equivalent of `#include` within each of the `proj-X/CMakeLists.txt` files? Would there be an issue due to running the same commands twice (once on the root `CMakeLists.txt` and another on the `proj-X/CMakeLists.txt` file, when starting the build from the root)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to rework some of your CMakeLists.txt files.

I would recommend watching [Daniel Pfeifer's Effective CMake talk at CPPcon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsXLMQ6WgIk&t=5s) (slides available [here](https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2017/blob/master/05-19-2017_friday/effective_cmake__daniel_pfeifer__cppnow_05-19-2017.pdf)).

The gist of it is that all of your projects should provide everything they need in order to be build or compiled, in essence build requirements and usage requirements. To achieve this in a maintainable and scalable way you have to move away from variables and setting global options (`add_compile_options`, `include_directories`, etc) and instead focus on targets (`target_compile_options`, `target_include_directories`, etc).

So, in your case `proj-1/CMakeLists.txt` will provide one target (let's call it `proj::proj1`) that sets the proper `PUBLIC` and `INTERFACE` options (by options I mean needed compiler features, dependencies, include directories, etc).

An abstract example:

```
project(proj1)

add_library(proj1 src.cpp)
# This are private include files, whoever uses this library does not need them
target_include_directories(proj1 PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
# These are public, needed both by this target and by whoever uses it.
target_include_directories(proj1 PUBLIC
    # This is used when building the target
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/public/include>
    # This is used when the target is installed
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
# Instead of asking directly for a language standard we ask for a compiler feature. We make this public so whoever depends on this target knows they also need this feature.
target_compile_features(proj1 PUBLIC cxx_strong_enums)
# As above, but this is needed only by this target during the build.
target_compile_features(proe1 PRIVATE cxx_lambdas)

# Add an alias, users can use target_link_libraries(target PRIVATE|PUBLIC proj::proj1) to add this target as a dependency (this will propagate all the PUBLIC include paths, compile options, compile features, dependencies, etc.
add_library(proj::proj1 ALIAS proj1)
```

This is highly abstract, it depends on what you're actually doing in your build scripts, it's hard to give a better explanation than Daniel Pfeifer, so I recommend watching his talk or at least reading the slides. It will make your build scripts a lot easier to write, read, and use.

Another great resource is [this site](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/).

Comment: Thank you so much, I will review the slides. Still: does that mean that every single option should go into its own `proj-X/CMakeLists.txt` file? What if I have, say, 10 different options which are common to all of them? It doesn't feel like the right way is repeating these 10 different options in every file.

Comment: That's a bit of a problem indeed. The first approach that comes to mind is to add  the common options in a variable in the root `CMakeLists.txt` and then use `target_*` to add them to specific targets. However, if you want to compile one project as a stand alone project you won't have the options. You can have an interface library that bundles those options and link against it, but then the question is where do you put that library and how do you find it? I don't know of a good generic way of handling this.

Comment: One alternative is to always build from the root project, but to have options for disabling targets that you don't need. But this will not work if you want to provide a package with only one of the sub projects.